# how can i list mongoose schema fields and their types recursively?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a complex database (monogdb) structure i need to access via mongoose (node.js)
i've built schemes and models.
now - i need to be able to access the field names and field type of every schema from the client and from other places (i.e: in order to create forms, validate types, present tooltips etc)
the problem - i have many embedded types..
i there a way to do this easily?
(i've managed to iterate over the 'Schema.paths' but it some objects there have the 'instance' field, some don't, some have Schema inside etc..

exmaple for one of my sub-schemes:

```
var labelSpanType = {type: Number, min:0};//"description" : "a numeric type to use for Label spans",
var labelType = new Schema({
    "@name": String,
    "@start": labelSpanType,
    "@end": labelSpanType,
    "@fgColor": RGBColorType,
    "@bgColor": RGBColorType,
    "@itype": {type: "string",enum: ["APos","CNI","INI","DNI","INC"]},
    "@feID": Number,
    "@cBy": String
}, {_id:false});

var layerType = new Schema({
    "label": [labelType],
    "@name": String,
    "@rank": orderType
},{_id:false});
```

Comment: Have a look at Mongoose Forms https://github.com/GothAck/forms-mongoose

Comment: thanks, i checked it out, but it seems that it can't handle well with arrays (i.e: 'fieldname: {type: [String], forms: {all:{}}}')
it is throwing exception in this case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I discover all available properties when using a jQuery UI widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161920/how-do-i-discover-all-available-properties-when-using-a-jquery-ui-widget)